# Shopify API - Can't find orders created by another application

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to find all of my store's orders, and found out that I can only received list of manually created orders, but not orders created by another applications throughout APIs.

Here my current orders list:
[image]

And here my code to find all orders

`temp = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all, :params=>{:status => 'any', :fields => 'name'})`

or find single order with order_id

`order = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(show_params['order_id'])`

The 1st line of code return only 1 order (#1013) created by me

`[#<ShopifyAPI::Order:0x0000000c6ae170 @attributes={"name"=>"#1013"}, @prefix_options={}, @persisted=true>]`

The 2nd line of code raised error:

`#<ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound: Failed.  Response code = 404.  Response message = Not Found (Not Found).>`

Note that all of my other orders except #1013 created by 3rd-application:

[image]

What should I do now to find all my orders?

Thank in advance.

P/s: I use `2020-01` api version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `read_orders` scope grants you access to get orders created not earlier than 60 days ago.

You have to [request `read_all_orders` scope](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-a-public-app-with-oauth/#orders-permissions) to be able to fetch all orders now.

Comment: Oh. I forgot about it. Thank you so much.